# Please could someone check my results for principal values of the complex logarithm?

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I solved an exercise in my book and would greatly appreicate it if someone would check my result and tell me if it is correct:.

The exercise: Find the principal values of the logarithm for the following numbers: $i,-i,-1, x \in \mathbb R_{>0}, 1 +i$.

My answer: The book defines the principal value to be in $(-\pi , \pi]$.

$$\newcommand{\Log}{\operatorname{Log}}\newcommand{\Arg}{\operatorname{Arg}} \Log(i) = \log 1 + i \Arg(i) = i {\pi \over 2} $$

$$ \Log(-i) = \log 1 + i \Arg(-i) = -i {\pi \over 2} $$

$$ \Log(-1) = \log 1 + i \Arg(-1) = i \pi  $$

$$ \Log x = \log x$$

$$ \Log(1+i) = \log \sqrt{2} + i {\pi \over 4}$$

where I use $\log$ to denote the real logarithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computations look good.

(For completeness, you should be aware of the fact that many texts leave the principle branch of $\log$ *undefined* on the negative real axis, i.e.: $\operatorname{Arg}(z) \in (-\pi, \pi)$.)